# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_openat", referenced from: _vlc_openat in MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, mobile, linker-errors, vlc

I want to play online stream use vlc in iOS.
I find this
http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html
to do that and can run SimplePlayback source code in simulator.
But when build it for iOS device, I get same error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/Data/Projects/B2/Document/VLCKit-2.2.0-rc1/Examples_iOS/SimplePlayback/../../build/Release-iphonesimulator"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/Data/Projects/B2/Document/VLCKit-2.2.0-rc1/Examples_iOS/SimplePlayback/../../build/Release-iphonesos"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/ali/Downloads/build'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_openat", referenced from:
  _vlc_openat in MobileVLCKit(lt4-filesystem.o)
 (maybe you meant: _vlc_openat)
"_fdopendir", referenced from:
  _DirRead in MobileVLCKit(libfilesystem_plugin_la-directory.o)
  _FileOpen in MobileVLCKit(libfilesystem_plugin_la-file.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can any one help me?
Thanks

Comment: Fixed formatting of the error messages